# Wordpress query based on custom date field and time field

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using a WordPress Calendar plugin to show multiple events. These events start on different days on different times. The plugin works fine and shows all the the events.

But I wanna display just the future events. E.g., if an event starts at August 1st at 11am, the event should be hidden at the same time. I tried to solve my problem with this query:

```
add_filter('cmcal_calendar_posts_query', 'calendar_return_specific_events', 10, 2);

function calendar_return_specific_events($query_args, $calendar_id) {
    if ($calendar_id == 110) {
        $todays_date = current_time('d.m.Y');
        $right_now = current_time('H:i');
        $query_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => '-1',
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                'date_clause' => array(
                    'key' => 'start_date',
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'value' => $todays_date,
                ),
                'time_clause' => array(
                    'key' => 'start_time',
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'value' => $right_now,
                ),
            ),
            'orderby' => array(
                'date_clause' => 'ASC',
                'time_clause' => 'ASC',
            )
        );
    }
    return $query_args;
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you post the actual result vs the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set key 'type' in your 'meta_query' array. The code would be something like this:

```
add_filter('cmcal_calendar_posts_query', 'calendar_return_specific_events', 10, 2);

function calendar_return_specific_events($query_args, $calendar_id) {
    if ($calendar_id == 110) {
        $todays_date = current_time('d.m.Y');
        $right_now = current_time('H:i');
        $query_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => '-1',
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                 array(
                    'key' => 'start_date',
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'value' => $todays_date,
                    'type' => 'DATE' //set the format
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'start_time',
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'value' => $right_now,
                    'type' => 'DATE' //set the format
                ),
            ),
            'orderby' => array(
                'date_clause' => 'ASC',
                'time_clause' => 'ASC',
            )
        );
    }
    return $query_args;
}
```

Comment: Cheers Alexandr. Great job. It works now.